# How to add np.nan if Regex condition match in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have the following dataframe:

```
d_test = {
    'latitude' : [40.765004, 45.504641, 40.00000, -34.283007],
    'longitude' : [-73.965961, 122.000000, -90.121679, -118.439891],
    'test': [1,2,3,4],
}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(d_test)
```

I want to use Regex `r'^[+-]?[0-9]*[.][0]*?$` to put `np.nan` if condition matches.
I know how to filter result completely using regex:

```
df_test[~df_test[['latitude', 'longitude']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains(r'^[+-]?[0-9]*[.][0]*?$', regex=True)).any(axis=1)]
```

the code above gives:

```
     latitude   longitude     test
0   40.765004   -73.965961     1
3   -34.283007  -118.439891    4
```

but I need the following result:

```
     latitude   longitude    test
0   40.765004   -73.965961    1
1   NaN          NaN          2
2   NaN          NaN          3
3   -34.283007  -118.439891   4
```

I tried to use pandas' `where`:

```
~df_[['latitude', 'longitude']].where(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains(r'^[+-]?[0-9]*[.][0]*?$', regex=True))
```

but it does not work (`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'`)

Comment: I don’t think using regex to manipulate geospatial data is the best approach. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @PaulH This data represents locations of restaurants in the word. But some lat-long were damaged and no longer represent those locations. For example it is highly unlikely that lat-long (40.00000, -90.121679) represent a real place because the lat is too precise

Comment: Using modulo would be a much more efficient way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use [*boolean indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) with [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.htmlb) :

```
m = df_test.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains(r'^[+-]?[0-9]*[.][0]*?$', regex=True)).any(axis=1)
​
df_test.loc[m, ["latitude", "longitude"]] = np.NaN
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df_test)
    latitude   longitude  test
0  40.765004  -73.965961     1
1        NaN         NaN     2
2        NaN         NaN     3
3 -34.283007 -118.439891     4
```

Comment: if `d_test` has additional columns e.g. `d_test = {
    'latitude' : [40.765004, 45.504641, 40.00000, -34.283007],
    'longitude' : [-73.965961, 122.000000, -90.121679, -118.439891],
    'test': [1,2,3,4],
}` your solution will put `NaN` on entire row (`test` column would look like `1, NaN, NaN, 4`)

Comment: Yes we can handle this one. Check my updated answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could just assign it back to the columns

```
df_test[['latitude', 'longitude']] = df_test[~df_test[['latitude', 'longitude']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains(r'^[+-]?[0-9]*[.][0]*?$', regex=True)).any(axis=1)]
```

Output

```
    latitude   longitude
0  40.765004  -73.965961
1        NaN         NaN
2        NaN         NaN
3 -34.283007 -118.439891
```

Comment: thanks, but it does not work (`ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`) if `df_test` has additional columns e.g. `d_test = {
    'latitude' : [40.765004, 45.504641, 40.00000, -34.283007],
    'longitude' : [-73.965961, 122.000000, -90.121679, -118.439891],
    'test': [1,2,3,4],
}`

Answer (score 0):

make your condintion to `cond1`

```
cond1 = ~df_test[['latitude', 'longitude']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains(r'^[+-]?[0-9]*[.][0]*?$', regex=True)).any(axis=1)
```

use `pandas where`

```
df_test.where(cond1)
```

output:

```
   latitude   longitude
0  40.765004  -73.965961
1        NaN         NaN
2        NaN         NaN
3 -34.283007 -118.439891
```

Comment: if `d_test` has additional columns e.g. `d_test = {
    'latitude' : [40.765004, 45.504641, 40.00000, -34.283007],
    'longitude' : [-73.965961, 122.000000, -90.121679, -118.439891],
    'test': [1,2,3,4],
}` your solution will put `NaN` on entire row (`test` column would look like `1, NaN, NaN, 2`)

Comment: I think you should make examples solve your problem, and you should be able to apply examples to your own dataset. I think that only solving examples is my job. It is not difficult to use my code and apply it to your dataset. it just need a little effort

Comment: appreciate your input but please note I changed my question to match my comment so your answer do not provide desired output. Also I do not ask about my dataset I am still asking only about very specific example. Thanks.